# scipy.minimize 'SLSQP' appears to return sub optimal weights values

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, machine-learning, scipy, ensemble-learning

Im trying to run a minimization function for an ensemble of logloss values, however when using the scipy.minimize function it appears to return a sub optimal value.

The data comes in a pandas table:

click, prob1, prob2, prob3

0, 0.0023, 0.0024, 0.012

1, 0.89, 0.672, 0.78

0, 0.43, 0.023, 0.032

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize 
from math import log
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def logloss(p, y):
  p = max(min(p, 1 - 10e-15), 10e-15)
  return -log(p) if y == 1 else -log(1 - p)

def ensemble_weights(weights, probs, y_true):
  loss = 0
  final_pred = []
  prob_length = len(probs)

  for i in range(prob_length):
    w_sum = 0
    for index, weight in enumerate(weights):
      w_sum += probs[i][index] * weight

      final_pred.append(w_sum)

    for index, pred in enumerate(final_pred):
      loss += logloss(pred, y_true[index])
      print loss / prob_length, 'weights :=', weights
  return loss / prob_length


## w0 is the initial guess for the minimum of function 'fun'
## This initial guess is that all weights are equal
w0 = [1/probs.shape[1]] * probs.shape[1]

# ## This sets the bounds on the weights, between 0 and 1
bnds = [(0,1)] * probs.shape[1]
## This sets the constraints on the weights, they must sum to 1
## Or, in other words, 1 - sum(w) = 0
cons = ({'type':'eq','fun':lambda w: 1 - np.sum(w)})

weights = minimize(
    ensemble_weights,
    w0,
    (probs,y_true),
    method='SLSQP',
    bounds=bnds,
    constraints=cons
)
## As a sanity check, make sure the weights do in fact sum to 1
print("Weights sum to %0.4f:" % weights['fun'])
print weights['x']
```

To help debug i've used a print statement in the function for this which returns the following.

0.0101326509533 weights := [ 1.  0.  0.]

0.0101326509533 weights := [ 1.  0.  0.]

0.0101326509702 weights := [ 1.00000001  0.          0.        ]

0.0101292476389 weights := [  1.00000000e+00   1.49011612e-08   0.00000000e+00]

0.0101326509678 weights := [  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.49011612e-08]

0.0102904525781 weights := [ -4.44628778e-10   1.00000000e+00  -4.38298620e-10]

0.00938612854966 weights := [  5.00000345e-01   4.99999655e-01  -2.19149158e-10]

0.00961930211064 weights := [  7.49998538e-01   2.50001462e-01  -1.09575296e-10]

0.00979499597866 weights := [  8.74998145e-01   1.25001855e-01  -5.47881403e-11]

0.00990978430231 weights := [  9.37498333e-01   6.25016666e-02  -2.73943942e-11]

0.00998305685424 weights := [  9.68748679e-01   3.12513212e-02  -1.36974109e-11]

0.0100300175342 weights := [  9.84374012e-01   1.56259881e-02  -6.84884901e-12]

0.0100605546439 weights := [  9.92186781e-01   7.81321874e-03  -3.42452299e-12]

0.0100807513117 weights := [  9.96093233e-01   3.90676721e-03  -1.71233067e-12]

0.0100942930446 weights := [  9.98046503e-01   1.95349723e-03  -8.56215139e-13]

0.0101034594634 weights := [  9.99023167e-01   9.76832595e-04  -4.28144378e-13]

0.0101034594634 weights := [  9.99023167e-01   9.76832595e-04  -4.28144378e-13]

0.0101034594804 weights := [  9.99023182e-01   9.76832595e-04  -4.28144378e-13]

0.0101034593149 weights := [  9.99023167e-01   9.76847497e-04  -4.28144378e-13]

0.010103459478 weights := [  9.99023167e-01   9.76832595e-04   1.49007330e-08]

Weights sum to 0.0101:

[  9.99023167e-01   9.76832595e-04  -4.28144378e-13]

My expectation would be that the optimal weights returned should be:
0.00938612854966 weights := [  5.00000345e-01   4.99999655e-01  -2.19149158e-10]

Can anyone see a glaring issue?

FYI -> This code is really a hack of the kaggle otto script
https://www.kaggle.com/hsperr/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/finding-ensamble-weights

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
options = {'ftol':1e-9}
```

as part of the minimize function